# Finding negative 2nd moment of gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-function, moment-generating-functions, gamma-distribution

Given a gamma distribution with shape $\alpha=2$ and rate $\lambda=10$, I was first asked to find an expression for $\Bbb E[X^k] \  \forall \  k \in \Bbb N$. Directly computing this, I got $$\Bbb E[X^k]=\frac{\Gamma(k+\alpha)}{\lambda^k\Gamma(\alpha)}.$$
Now I am asked to find an expression for $\Bbb E[X^{-2}]$, which given my parameters, would result in the above expression including $\Gamma(0)$ which is not defined. How should I go about this calculation, and is simply using the moment generating function the only way to do so? I understand that the MGF can only be used for **nonnegative** *k*, so I don't think that will work.

Comment: $EX^{-2}=\infty$.

Comment: How did you arrive at this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$EX^{-2}=100\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 x e^{-10x}\, dx$. Since $e^{-10x} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ and $\int_0^{1} \frac 1 x \, dx=\infty$ it follows that $EX^{-2}=\infty$.